# Android Studio cloud end point newly anotated method not showing up

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints, android-c2dm

I m new to google cloud endpoint.I m using android studio-0.8.14. I made a new GCM End Point module with the default template.Then I added annotations for find method (which is by default NOT annotated)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "findDevice")
private RegistrationRecord findRecord(@Named("regId") String regId) 
{
 return ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).filter("regId", regId).first().now();
}
```

After rerunning this module,I dont get the new api for find in my api explorer.I tried rebuilding the project but no luck.I think I need to regenerate the end point library for client. Eclipse had such option but android studio doesnt have that.What if I make a entity model class and then add end point class for that all by myself, without using studio template code, will it show up in explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got it to work BUT after updating the android studio and using their NEW TEMPLATE for endpoint module. The module I created was created before the android studio update beta-0.8.14.That means there must be a bug. Normally a public endpoint method should be exposed to api explorer even if u dont annotate.But in my case it didnt with or without annotation. I did everything ,rebuilding the project, restarting the module backend etc but still no luck. Then I created another project and build anther module with A NEW module-building wizard, I found that the whole project structure changed A LOT...A LOT. Then I added a module (with and without annotation) which just showed up in the API explorer after restarting the backend module. Hence I think the problem must have been in the earlier module template code or somewhere else.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I add a new model to my google backend, it is picked up automatically and i can refer to the model within my android app. However, if i add a new endpoint, it cannot be found.